# Is there a way to tag messages for billing porpuse?

Tags: twilio

I'm searching a way to annotate my messages by some grouping logic, but I couldn't find any reference online.

The goal is simply to get drill down monthly billing report that show the cost for each group.

I don't want to use different senders, as it won't scale on the application side

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the /Messages statusCallback parameter and associate a URL query parameter(s) that associates that message with a group.

Comment: does it means I'll need to collect this data on my own, or will it have any groupping on twilio billing reports?

Comment: Correct, you would handle the grouping on your side.